# Azure Pipeline Parameter with date as default

Tags: azure-pipelines

Having a Pipeline which needs some manual Input I tried to set the current date formated as default value like this

```
parameters:
  - name: StartDate
    displayName: StartDate
    type: string
    default: $(Date:dd/MM/yyyy)
```

but it shows just the text. It has to be a string because later it is used as arm template input.

Is there a way to give current date a default value ?
maybe even calculated as year plus two !?

regards for any hint on that

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables to get Date.

```
trigger:
- main

variables:
    SDate:  $[format('{0:yyyy}/{0:MM}/{0:dd}/{0:HH}{0:mm}{0:ss}', pipeline.startTime)]

parameters:
  - name: StartDate
    displayName: StartDate
    type: string
    default: $(SDate)

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo "The start date is - ${{ parameters.StartDate }}"
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And extra Kodus for really trying it out

Answer (score 0):

By not adding the default value, you can manually enter the value for testing purpose.

```
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - main/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: startDate
    displayName: startDate
    type: string

jobs:
- job: Date
  displayName: customDate
  steps:
  - script: echo "The start date is - ${{ parameters.startDate }}"
```

you will get an answer like this, later you can format this value as per your need.
The start date is - 10/23/2022

Comment: Thanks for that. It helps during the pipeline run but it does not help during manual run where the user would have the chance to set a parameter. I would need that for testing purposes

Comment: thanks for that, still does not change anything to the default value of the parameters